overflow on power for decimal number recursively in python
so im trying to do recursive call to solve function that take integer argument and do recursively, and each recursive call, it power to decimal number i.e 2.2
def f1(x):
    if x==0:
        return 3
    else:
        return f1(x-1)**2.2

aw=f1(13)
print("succces")



as you can see, that the code above will generate output like below instead of "succes":
File "/home/user/Dev/Programs/tesaja.py", line 19, in f1
return f1(x-1)**2.2
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
i know that this might caused by floating point mechanism in python that only store limited digit, while int (if the power number is int) can hold bigger int, as mentioned below:
https://ksvi.mff.cuni.cz/~dingle/2021-2/prog_1/notes_2.html
e.g:
def f1(x):
    if x==0:
        return 3
    else:
        return f1(x-1)**3

aw=f1(13)
print("succces")



this will output fine/"succes" even the power number is 3 (bigger than 2.2)
i dunno if there is similiar problem with me since i wandering around stackofervlow and didnt find same spesific problem (duplicate)," some of it dont include recursive and power floating point"
so i hope you guys can give me solution and more insight about what caused this problem occured

Re: "i wandering around stackofervlow and didnt find same spesific problem" Using the term python OverflowError float recursive site:stackoverflow.com in both duckduckgo and google will return this linked answer within the first 5 links.  In short, use the Decimal type.

@metatoaster but this solution doesnt solve general issue, i tried it but it only extend/solve better solution (i got up to 10 recursion with result) but still cant give the amount of result if i use integer as the power number

If your next error is ValueError: Exceeds the limit for integer string conversion;, follow the advice in the next sentence (or this thread). Otherwise please update your question with the specific problem and error that you've faced; your original question was fine, it was minimal, verifiable and reproducible, but has been asked before. If it's something novel please modify your question to reflect that. Do search first for the issue you came across, using the error message helps.

i apply some of your refrence solution as i said in my earlier comment in my other recursive function, for f(19) its fine but when f(20) it show
decimal.Overflow: [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]

Please search the specific exception first, because you would have found this thread which talks about the limits of the Decimal type and how might that be configured.

as i mentioned ealier, the problem is floating point mechanism inside python, so decimal wont work, i know an external module that can solve this, called mpmath, but since for a particular reason, i dont want any external module to solve this. but yeah still stuck in this problem

What do you mean by decimal doesn't work? I changed the first example to return f1(x-1)**Decimal('2.2') and f1(13) produced Decimal('2.944194192311332558630579003E+13493') as the result. Following the working with big numbers in python and set the Emax to maximum, f(19) produced Decimal('1.644535567629722527528571309E+1529888'). This will work all the way up to f1(53), as going further you will run into the maximum limits offered by Decimal.

Moreover, you can't use float for what you want because limits do exist, and this is the standard limit of the IEEE 754 standard.
